# would deleting copy constructor/assignment break standard library operations

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, constructor, stl

I have a few classes with requirements that their instances must not have similar copies at runtime. Let's say one of the class looks like -

```
class A{
    int id;
    int printerNum;

    bool failState = true;
    //....

public:
    //....

};
```

Now `id` and `printerNum` must be unique to each instance since no two instance can control same printer at a time. `id` is only generated at construction of the object but `printerNum` can change. For these two requirements, I provide checks at constructor and a `failState` variable which never initializes the object properly and sets the `failState` to true if something bad occurs.

Also I was thinking of deleting the copy constructor and assignment operator to make sure a user never creates a copy and can only initialize it from constructor so that id and printerNum remain unique.

But before making this change I was thinking of asking, would this break other algorithms and containers available inside the standard namespace? They might be using assignment operators and copy constructors often and what would happen if I delete these explicitly like -

```
// no copy
A(const A&) = delete;

// no assign
A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
```

If not possible, or there's another way to do this, I would welcome all suggestions. Thankyou :)

Comment: If it would, it would not compile.

Comment: you can still define copy constructor & assignment operator as private in your class.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre what would be the possible benefit? It still wouldn't be accessible, right?

Comment: you could never do `a1=a2` or `A a2(a1);` isn't what you want?

Comment: @Tobias no subtle failures/undefined scenarios? I'm quite skeptical of them atm with cpp given I'm still learning it.

Comment: @hg_git No -- since all calls will be resolved by the compiler.

Comment: I didn't get if you want to avoid un-controlled copies or just make sure each copy has different id. In the last case you can create an unique-id for each copy.

Comment: @BiagioFesta I've said that option exists but what about `printerNum` then? It has to be unique and even if I assign 0 or something to it, that becomes entirely different object now. Now if I want to sort an vector, and what I get is a vector of entirely different objects, that's not a good way to do things...

Comment: I cannot understand. `printNum` can be setted with a method?

Comment: @BiagioFesta There are atmost 3 printers (hardware device). Only 3 objects can exist at max holding access to those printers. Hence `printerNum`. `printerNum = 2` means 2nd printer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++11,  the requirements to the types used in the containers depend on  the operations you call.
The only thing which they require unconditionally is that type is `Erasable`, which, when used with standard allocator, is equivalent to requiring `p->~T()` to be well-formed and valid.

So, copy-construction is required when vector is reallocated or copy-construction version of insert is used. Assignment is needed when, for example, elements are inserted in  the middle of the vector, or container is sorted.

For example, here is a quote from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector on `vector`:

> The requirements that are imposed on the elements depend on the actual
>   operations performed on the container. Generally, it is required that
>   element type is a complete type and meets the requirements of
>   Erasable, but many member functions impose stricter requirements.

Comment: on operations like copy-construction or later, is it guaranteed that those two objects will not exist simultaneously after it completes? It should delete either the copy or original at the end right?

Comment: @hg_git, I am  not sure if I understand the question. Can you please clarify a bit?

Comment: say I have an `vector` with 3 objects, with member `int a` `=` `1, 2 & 3` respectively. During reallocation, there must be a time when copy constructor call will make a copy of say object with member `a = 1`. So at that moment, two identical objects exist, right? Considering value of member `a` determines the uniqueness.

Comment: @hg_git, it will try to move, so if your type implements move semantics, object will be moved, not copied. For non-movable objects, a copy would exist.